# Cannot able to print header or footer while generating PDF document via phpexcel library

Tags: pdf, header, phpexcel, footer

I am generating PDFdocument via PHPExcel library, I've set the header & footer sections by below code. But when I open the pdf  document I dont see any header or footer.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('&C&HPlease treat this document as confidential!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('&L&B' . $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->getTitle() . '&RPage &P of &N');
```

Comment: which pdf library are you use to create pdf?

Comment: That's because headers/footers are only saved for the Excel5/Excel2007 Writers

Comment: **mpdf** and Excel5